# Running Stored Procedure in Oracle DB and run it using batch scripting

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql

I have a stored procedure in an Oracle database and I want to create a batch file that can call and run the said procedure. After running the stored procedure I want to call a certain sql file then run it also within just a single batch file.

- name of stored procedure = `health_check`
- name of SQL file = `spool1.sql`

I want to run the stored procedure first in the batch file. Upon success I want to call the said sql file then run it still at the same batch file.

I'm already able to execute the sql file. I just want to add the calling and running of the stored procedure in my current batch file

I want to achieve something like this:

```
@echo off
--run proc here
sqlplus user/password@DB @D:\mysqlfile.sql
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, its is possible.

Comment: Are you really sure you want this question answered? you know there are two answer only: 'yes' or 'no'. Perhaps you should be a bit more precise. Maybe provide a [mcve]. Please also read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try something, do some search and attempts and then, if you have an issue with your code, your question will be welcome here.

Comment: name of store proc = health_check
name of sql file = spool1.sql

I want to run the stored proc first in the batch file.
Upon succession I want to call the said sql file then run it still at the same batch file.

I'm already able to execute the sql file. I just want to add the calling and running of the stored proc in
my current batch file

I want to achieve something like this.
@echo off
--run proc here
sqlplus user/password@DB @D:\mysqlfile.sql

Comment: this might help https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a 'heredec' approach:

```
@echo off
@(
echo execute health_check
echo @D:\mysqlfile.sql
) | sqlplus -s -l user/password@DB
```

Untested but this pattern should work. Everythign in the parentheses is evaluated, which produces two lines of output:

```
execute health_check
@D:\mysqlfile.sql
```

and those are treated as input by SQL*Plus. So it's the equivalent of an interactive session where you start SQL*Plus and then enter those two lines in turn at the `SQL>` prompt. The `@<file>` can be used from that prompt too to run the file contents. And `execute` (or just `exec`) is a client shortcut for an anonymous PL/SQL block.

This assumes, based on how you did this in your question, that the `.sql` file ends with an `exit`. If it doesn't then you can add then to the heredoc with `echo exit`.

Comment: I think @ before opening parenthesis is unnecessary here because echo is off.

Comment: @Alex Poole, the above code works. Thank you very much

Comment: just a follow up question what is the use of -s -l from the last line?

Comment: @JCBA - the `-s` suppresses the banner and the `SQL>` prompts from the output, useful for non-interactive scripts. The `-l` stop it prompting for credentials if the first login fails, which can stop things getting stuck - habit to add those... [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169506).

Comment: @Alex Poole, Thank you very much.